# Separate out a crowded ListPlot image

Tags: plotting

I have a ListPlot generated image that contains points that are very close to one another and total more than 15000 in number. As a result they appear to be virtually on top of one another. How do I enlarge the image and save it so that the points appear separated? The "drag the corner of the bounding box" trick to make the image larger does not work as the computer hangs when I do this, possibly due to the large amount of information that has to be manipulated.

Comment: Try using the ImageSize option to ListPlot to make the figure start out larger.

Comment: Also try `PlotMarkers->{Automatic,.01}` option.

Comment: Sadly, I need the PlotMarkers to be numerals as I want each plot to be labelled by an integer ...